# How hard is to reverse engineer a signature for a given message?

Tags: digital-signature, sha, integrity, reverse-engineering

**Given the following situation:**

- User makes a request for temporary access to a video
- Backend responds with a json file containing `timeAllowedInSeconds: 5`
- Backend also responds with the signature of the json, a 40-character hexadecimal string
- User sends back both json and signature
- Permission is granted

If the signature is a simple SHA1 of the json, then the user can simply edit the time allowed to 20 seconds, hash the json and send that information back.

What's a secure algorithm to generate the signature? Is appending some secret text that the user doesn't know at the end enough?

Is it feasible to reverse engineer the method by which the signature was generated? Other than randomly manipulating the json file that is being signed?

Comment: A SHA1 is not a "signature". That's just a hash or a checksum. Did you mean to use the term "signature"?

Comment: Use an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) if you want to add a secret to the hash.

Comment: @nobody I keep forgetting that HMAC is a solution for things. Thanks.

Comment: @schroeder Is see HMAC (or keyed SHA3) as "symmetric signatures". They only lack the non-repudiation properties of asymmetric signatures. And this property is not often needed in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Adding even a UUID or some unique string (it doesn't need to be secret) to the JSON means that it will be extremely difficult to generate a matching hash if the JSON is edited.

You don't need to keep the string a secret or even the hash type you use. Just match the unique string to the hash in a lookup table on the backend. That way you have near 100% assurance that the json you got back was the json you sent.

This is what hashes do and are good at.